# How to properly format data with AppSync and DynamoDB when Lambda is in between

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

Receiving data with AppSync directly from DynamoDB seems working for my case, but when I try to put a lambda function in between, I receive errors that says *"Can't resolve value (/issueNewMasterCard/masterCards) : type mismatch error, expected type LIST"*

Looking to the AppSync cloudwatch response mapping output, I get this:

```
 "context": {
        "arguments": {
            "userId": "18e946df-d3de-49a8-98b3-8b6d74dfd652"
        },
        "result": {
            "Item": {
                "masterCards": {
                    "L": [
                        {
                            "M": {
                                "cardId": {
                                    "S": "95d67f80-b486-11e8-ba85-c3623f6847af"
                            },
                                "cardImage": {
                                    "S": "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/logo.png"
                                },
                                "cardWallet": {
                                    "S": "0xFDB17d12057b6Fe8c8c434653456435634565"
                                },...............
```

here is how I configured my response mapping template:

```
$utils.toJson($context.result.Item)
```

I'm doing this mutation:

```
mutation IssueNewMasterCard {
  issueNewMasterCard(userId:"18e946df-d3de-49a8-98b3-8b6d74dfd652"){
    masterCards {
      cardId
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my schema :

```
type User {
    userId: ID!
    masterCards: [MasterCard]
}

type MasterCard {
    cardId: String
}

type Mutation {
    issueNewMasterCard(userId: ID!): User
}
```

The Lambda function:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    const userId = event.arguments.userId;

         const userParam = {
              Key: {
                 "userId":{S:userId}
              },
              TableName:"FidelityCardsUsers"
             }

      dynamoDB.getItem(userParam, function(err, data) {

        if (err) {
            console.log('error from DynamDB: ',err)
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log('mastercards: ',JSON.stringify(data));
            callback(null,data)
        }

 })
```

Comment: Hi- can you give an outline of your lambda function to please (especially your return value)?

Comment: @thomasmichaelwallace here you go, feel free to ask if you need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `getItem` you use when you use the DynamoDB datasource is not the same as the the `DynamoDB.getItem` function in the aws-sdk.

Specifically it seems like the datasource version returns an already marshalled response (that is, instead of `something: { L: [ list of things ] }` it just returns `something: [ list of things]`).

This is important, because it means that `$utils.toJson($context.result.Item)` in your current setup is returning `{ masterCards: { L: [ ...` which is why you are seeing the type error- `masterCards` in this case is an object with a key `L`, rather than an array/list.

To solve this in the resolver, you can use the `$util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson(Object)` macro (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html#dynamodb-helpers-in-util-dynamodb). i.e. your resolver should be:

```
$util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($context.result.Item)
```

Alternatively you might want to look at the `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` class (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html). This includes versions of `getItem`, etc. that automatically marshal and unmarshall the proprietary DynamoDB typing back into native JSON. (Frankly I find this much nicer to work with and use it all the time).

In that case you *can* keep your old resolver, because you'll be returning an object where `masterCards` *is* just a JSON array.

Comment: The `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` class was the right solution for my case, thx Thomas.